# Openvpn systemd service won't connect automatically to profile

Tags: debian, systemd, openvpn

I am running an OpenVPN client on a Debian 12 machine.
In `/etc/openvpn/` I have the configuration file (`client.conf`) and another file (`login.txt`) with username and password.

When I try to reboot or restart OpenVPN service it simply does not connect to the server and in the syslog there's no log at all, as if there wasn't even the configuration file in the folder.

Syslog output when I restart the service:

```
2023-10-12T00:52:55.350023+02:00 server systemd[1]: Stopped openvpn.service - OpenVPN service.
2023-10-12T00:52:55.350231+02:00 server systemd[1]: Stopping openvpn.service - OpenVPN service...
2023-10-12T00:52:55.350480+02:00 server systemd[1]: Starting openvpn.service - OpenVPN service...
2023-10-12T00:52:55.350617+02:00 server systemd[1]: Finished openvpn.service - OpenVPN service.
```

I did configure `/etc/defaults/openvpn` to autostart "ALL" configuration files.

When trying to connect to the server using the command line, the client does connect to the server successfully (`openvpn --config client.conf`).